# Problem with converting Arabic to Roman numerals

Tags: java, numbers, converters, roman-numerals

I have a problem with a program that converts Arabic numerals to Roman. Everything works fine at first. But **when I input bigger numbers**, I have the **right output PLUS an extra number**.

Here's my code:

```
public class Persist {

/**
 *
 * @param number
 * @return finalAnswer
 */
public String solution(int number) {


    String nS = Integer.toString(number);
    String[] numbArray = nS.split("");
    String reverse = "";
    int count = 0;


    for(int y = numbArray.length - 1; y > -1; y--) {
        count++;

        int digit = Integer.parseInt(numbArray[y]);

        if(count == 1) {
            reverse = reverse.concat(rome("I", "V", "X", digit, reverse));
        }
        if(count == 2) {
            reverse = reverse.concat(rome("X", "L", "C", digit, reverse));
        }
        if(count == 3) {
            reverse = reverse.concat(rome("C", "D", "M", digit, reverse));
        }
    }

    //reverse a string
    String finalAnswer = "";
    for(int i = reverse.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        finalAnswer = finalAnswer + reverse.charAt(i);
    }

    return finalAnswer;
}



/**
 *
 * @param a, b, c - different Roman numerals
 * @param digit2 = digit
 * @param toReverse = reverse
 * @return toReverse = reverse
 */
public String rome(String a, String b, String c, int digit2, String toReverse) {

    if (digit2 == 0) {
        //do nothing
    }
    else if (digit2 > 0 && digit2 < 4) {
        for(int i = 0; i < digit2; i++) {
            toReverse = toReverse.concat(a);
        }
    }
    else if (digit2 == 4) {
        toReverse = toReverse.concat(b + a);
    }
    else if (digit2 > 4 && digit2 < 9) {
        for(int i = 0; i < (digit2 - 5); i++) {
            toReverse = toReverse.concat(a);
        }
        toReverse = toReverse.concat(b);
    }
    else if (digit2 == 9) {
        toReverse = toReverse.concat(c + a);
    }

    return toReverse;
}

}
```

And here's my testing:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
public class Testing {



private Persist conversion = new Persist();

@Test
public void shouldConvertToRoman() {
    assertEquals("solution(1) should equal to I", "I", conversion.solution(1));
    assertEquals("solution(4) should equal to IV", "IV", conversion.solution(4));
    assertEquals("solution(6) should equal to VI", "VI", conversion.solution(6));

    assertEquals("solution(501) should equal to DI", "DI", conversion.solution(501));
    assertEquals("solution(87) should equal to LXXXVII", "LXXXVII", conversion.solution(87));
    assertEquals("solution(578) should equal to DLXXVIII", "DLXXVIII", conversion.solution(578));
}
}
```

Output:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: solution(501) should equal to DI 
Expected :DI
Actual   :DIIII
```

So, it converts small numbers (from 1 to 10 included) just fine, but when the number is bigger it looks like it converts and prints the last digit of the number twice.

Comment: Unrelated: you can improve your naming. Calling a method `solution` tells the human reader ... nothing. There should be a verb, and it should say what it does. Like: `converToRoman()`, or even shorter `toRoman()`, or `asRoman()`. Also note: consider to use `assertThat()`, together with hamcrest mathers. Then you can write `assertThat(conversion.asRoman(501), is("DI))` ... which reads much more natural.

Comment: Also note that some of your code is overly complicated. You are using charAt() already, but you use split to slice your incoming number into chars, to then pick them from an array. No need to. Just use charAt to get the individual chars from the incoming string! Then: your javadoc ... is also not helpful. Keep in mind: when you write comments, their sole purpose is to EXPLAIN what the thing it talks about ... is about. Your comments only create confusion, as they explain nothing. It is better to NOT write comments, compared to writing content that is only confusing.

Comment: Finally: you are at a very important point of your exercise. "Thinking up an algorithm" ... and writing down code ... that is only the first half of your problem. Now it is about: debugging. Finding out what your code **actually** does, and where it deviates from your expectation. So, two choices. A) learn how to use a debugger or B) simply add a lot of print statements. You do not understand what exactly your code is doing. So get your code to TELL you what it is doing.

Comment: Additionally (and also useful when interacting with code you can't directly modify), you can add more test cases to try identify where the error is...  For example, your code gives: `11 -> XII`, `12 -> XIIII`, `13 -> XIIIIII`, and `14 -> XIVIV`.  Seems like you're likely duplicating some strings which shouldn't be duplicated, so you could look at places where you might be doing that.

Comment: Is 501 the only number that has a bug?

Comment: @NomadMaker no, it’s any number bigger than 10

Comment: I ran a test and am finding lots of errors.  Going from 1 to 3999 inclusive I only found 27 correct answers.  I also noticed a pattern.  Your correct answers are in the form of  `ABBB` where the `B`'s may be absent.  If A < B then only `A` and `AB` show up.  If `A > B` then you could have `A AB ABB or ABBB`

Comment: But it isn't consistent.   Eg. `CXXX and CXX  CX` show up as correct but `CIII CII CI` don't.  And although not a related issue, there is a `much simpler` way of doing this.